# Merge sorted lists Python

Tags: python, sorting, merge

Suppose we have two lists `L1` and `L2` that contain integers which are sorted in ascending order. I want to create a function `merge` that gets these lists as parameters and returns a new sorted list `L` that has all the elements of `L1` and `L2` i.e. `len(L) = len(L1) + len(L2)`. I want to do this using the fact that both lists are already sorted but I'm not allowed to use a sorting method when implementing the `merge` function.

Here is my code and I did not know why it's not right:

```
def merge(L1,L2):
    L = L1 + L2
    return L

def main():
    L1 = [1,2,5,9,12]
    L2 = [2,6,10]
    L = sorted(merge(L1,L2))
    print(L)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: You cannot use sorted to sort the output from your merge function.

Comment: Two lists are sorted. You can create another list. Check if L1[i] < L2[j] and append L1[i]  and increment i otherwise append L2[j] and increment j. Make sure you check the lengths of both list.

Comment: "You can however use these sorted in the main function for creating inputs to the merge function." That's not how you are using `sorted` here. You are using it to sort the result. That is not what they want. The way `merge` is supposed to work, the result will already be sorted.

Comment: I give you two piles of cards. Each is already sorted. I want you to make a pile of all the cards together, which is a sorted pile. But you are only allowed to take one card at a time from either pile, and put it on top of your result pile. Do you see how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you are not allowed to use `sorted`. You need to insert the elements into the new list one by one by iterating over both lists at the same time and picking the smallest element each time (since the lists are already sorted this is easy).

```
def merge(L1,L2):
    L = []
    # Keep 2 indices, one per list
    idx_L1 = 0
    idx_L2 = 0
    # Iterate over both lists at the same time
    while idx_L1 < len(L1) or idx_L2 < len(L2):
        # Check if we reached the end of any of the lists
        if idx_L1 == len(L1):
            L.append(L2[idx_L2])
            idx_L2 += 1
        elif idx_L2 == len(L2):
            L.append(L1[idx_L1])
            idx_L1 += 1
        # Add the smallest element from the two pointers
        elif L1[idx_L1] < L2[idx_L2]:
            L.append(L1[idx_L1])
            idx_L1 += 1
        else:
            L.append(L2[idx_L2])
            idx_L2 += 1
    return L

def main():
    L1 = [1,2,5,9,12]
    L2 = [2,6,10]
    L = merge(L1, L2)
    print(L)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```